# changing background color of browser field

Tags: blackberry

I am passing some html content to a browser field. The content is getting displayed with white background and black text. But I want to set the background color to black and the text color to white. Can anyone guide me how to achieve it?

Edit:

I am getting the html data from rss feed. So, i cant really apply the css or anything... I want to changes the background of the browser field and set text color to white instead of default black color...

Comment: Basic CSS? Or is there something more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this? http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-forms.shtml

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: black 2px solid;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can modify the HTML once you get it and apply the attributes directly.  For example:

```
<input name="q" style="background-color:#000000; color:#FFFFFF" type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value="search">
```